# ES python dsl, query, field name from variable

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Im using elasticsearch_dsl. 
Is it possible using Q to use field name from variable ?
I would like to field name topic_18 to be depended from variable.

```
   b_clause = Q(
                "range",
                topic_18={
                    "lte": 0.3
                }
            )
```

Like this:

```
field_name = "topic_12"
        clause = Q(
            "range",
            field_name={
                "lte": 0.3
            }
        )
```

is it possible ? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ok easy, instead of doing Q("range", ...
I did json like:

```
clause = {
            "range": {
              topic_name: {
                expr: val
              }
            }
         }
```

and later use it in final query:

```
Q("bool", must=must_arr)
```